# Laravel Canvas vendor files in the public folder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, webserver, public-html

I have installed the `austintoddj/canvas` package with my Laravel 10 application.

It has created a vendor directory in my public directory which contains css, js and the mix-manifest.json file.

I uploaded my files to my web server, but don't really know what to do with that vendor directory.
My structure is the following:

I have myproject folder, which contains all the project files but the content of the public folder.
In my public_html I have the content of the public directory with the vendor files as well (index.php points to myproject).
I feel like that shouldn't be there, but for some reason the package built that way. Does anyone have any experience with that? Where should I put that? Should I create a public folder in my myproject folder and place it there?

Thank you for the answers in advance.

This is an architectural question

Comment: why is your vendor inside public? did you composer install inside public?

Comment: when you deploy to web server/production, you just simply do composer install and npm install to install the packages needed in vendor and node_modules respectively.

Comment: are you uploading on "shared host" or "virtual server". are you using "GIT". and you didn`t need to copy vendor folder in public it should be nearby public folder

Comment: The composer update placed the vendor to the public folder